# vue-router route param to component prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I thought this would work:

```
  { path: '/course/:id', component: Course.extend({
    props: { course: params.id }
  }) },
```

Sadly, it's not that simple (it's not `id` either). How do I do this? (I just took a course on vue, can't believe I can't remember this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html), you have to make `props` option true in the `routes`, see below code to understand it:

```
const User = {
  props: ['id'],
  template: '<div>User {{ id }}</div>'
}
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, props: true }
  ]
})
```